# htc 516 dual sim doesnt boot. black screen. HELP!

Tags: partitions, swap

Yesterday i was able to root my HTC 516 dual sim. i decided to use my swap partition that i created on my sd card. installed app "Memory Swap" . 
it asked me to use the partition mmcblck1p2 or mmcblck0p2 imnot sure.

it was done displaying some terminal type messages about formatting.

i thought to restart to make changes take effect. it didnt turn on ever!

when i press on power button it makes a vibration but no light. took out battery several times, makes the vibration than nothing again.

when i connect to computer , pop up several drives maybe 10-15 , one drive is readable having 2 folder : images and verinfo.

USB device recognised as qhsusb_bulk .

things that i tried: from linux made a "dd" to partition aboot with my boot.img that i used for rooting. and also made a dumb to recovery partition with recovery.img that i found on the net for htc 516 DS . 
still no result!! 
which partitions i lost , and how can i bring them back ?

NOTE : after i successfully made the root , made a backup from adb_run . is that usable ? and how?

THANKS PLS HELP!!!